# display the user input via mouse/touch

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

So I'm working on a project with my pi4 where I use a touch foil for interaction. It behaves just like a regular mouse but without the cursor. So to set the foil up correctly I need an application to show me the current location of the users input (via touch) or a method to show the mouse cursor all the time.

thanks!

Comment: If you boot into a GUI on the rpi4, isn't the mouse cursor shown by default? Or are you looking for a command line application?

Comment: with the touch foil plugged in the cursor is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into [`evtest-qt`](https://github.com/Grumbel/evtest-qt), it is:

> ... a simple input device tester for Linux, it is analogous to the `evtest` command line tool, but with a Qt based GUI. It provides a list of attached input devices and displays which axis and buttons are pressed.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!